# Using Parent Scrollbar to scroll iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, scrollbar

**I want to use the parent scroll-bar to scroll a tall iframe.**

The problem: I need the bars to move in terms of percentage instead of per pixel. That would allow both bars to touch the bottom at the same time.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollTop) / (docHeight - winHeight);
    var scrollPercentRounded = Math.round(scrollPercent * 100);

    var divscrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var divdocHeight = $(document).height();
    var divwinHeight = $(window).height();
    var divscrollPercent = (divscrollTop) / (divdocHeight - divwinHeight);
    var divscrollPercentRounded = Math.round(divscrollPercent * 100);

    $('div').scrollTop((scrollPercentRounded * divscrollPercentRounded));

});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/RyanBrackett/xcw1yokm/

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your result? Stack Overflow isn't here to write code for you, or for simple suggestions of what to do.

Comment: I have tried a load of things to accomplish the non-embedded look, but realized after a while that simple scrolling the iframe with the browser scrollbar would do the same thing. Just looking here for suggestions.

Comment: What I mean is you need to post code you've written to try and solve the problem you're having. Detail what's not working with it, and what the expected outcome should be.

Comment: edited
http://jsfiddle.net/RyanBrackett/xcw1yokm/

Comment: Please include the code from your Fiddle in your answer. Fiddles can expire, so if that happens your question becomes useless. Also, please format your links properly. With over 300 rep you should be able to post links without any restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I no this is an old question, but one could also just disable the parent scrollbar and allow the iframe to be the main scrollbar. Of course this only works if you can set width 100% or 100vw.

In such a case one can instead just set the margin of all elements to 0px and overflow to hidden on containing parent.

Then set iframe to 100 vw and (optionally) 100 vh

The iframe is then 100% controlled by the parent containing scrollbar as seen below:

```css
    <style>
        * { margin:0px; }
        body {overflow:hidden;}
    </style>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://network.tactokens.com" style="min-width:100vw; min-height:100vh;">
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found this post and spend a few minutes playing with the code to make it work. Here's a my version of the coffee-script-code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
       $(document).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var scrollPercent = scrollTop / (docHeight - winHeight);

        var divHeight = $("div").height(); 
        var divContentHeight = $('div')[0].scrollHeight;

        var equation = scrollPercent * (divContentHeight-divHeight);

        $('div').scrollTop(equation);

    });

});
```

/ René

Comment: This is really great! My math was wrong somewhere, but this works like I need. Thanks, René!